# How to pass argument to a shell command in shell script from terminal

Tags: bash, shell

i am writing a shell script `practice.sh`. I want to give my first argument `$1` from command line to `ls` command in script.e.g
if I run my script in  terminal `$bash practice.sh *.mp3`
the argument `*.mp3`
I want to use for `ls` command

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$ls $1
```

it doesn't work
any help?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Just to help you understand what your program is actually doing: Since you never define the variable `ls`, your script defines an empty environment variable named _output_, and then runs the first argument supplied to your script as a command. You could see the effect when executing `$bash practice.sh printenv|grep output`, which will show the empty definition for output.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer for what you say you want is just

```
#!/bin/bash
ls "$1"
```

which will run `ls`, passing it (just) the first argument to the script.

However, you also say you want to run this like: `practice.sh *.mp3` which runs the script with *many* arguments (not just one) -- the `*.mp3` will be expanded to be all the of the .mp3 files in the current directory.  For that, you likely want something more like

```
#!/bin/bash
ls "$@"
```

which will pass *all* of the arguments to your script (however many there are) to the `ls` command.

These scripts will just run `ls` with its stdout connected to whatever your script has its stdout connceted to, so the output will (likely) just appear on your terminal.  If you instead want to *capture* the output of the `ls` command (so you can do something else with it), you need something like

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(ls "$@")
```

which will run `ls` with all the arguments, and capture the output in the variable `$output`.  You can then do things with that variable.

Comment: Note that `ls` is really intended for displaying a list of files to the user. If you want a list of files for the program to work on, it's best to use a wildcard or `find` instead. See ["Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

Use shell expansion to record the output of the command in the variable `output`:

```
output=$(ls $1)
```

This will record the output of the command `ls $1` in the variable `output`.
You can then use `echo $output` to print out your output.

You can read more about shell expansion in the [GNU Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf).